# Monitor new appended rows and create a ; separated file for each row

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a csv file on a linux server that has new rows appended in random times (can be every 1 sec and can be 2 hours with no new rows). The file looks as follows:

```
KEY PREDICTION  FIRST NAME  LAST NAME
aaaaaa  0           john    doe
bbbbbb  1           jane    doe
cccccc  1          michael  michael
dddddd  0           roger   rabit
```

lets say these are 4 new rows that were appended to the file - once the change of rows occurred I need to take the new N rows and create N colon-separated files in which the KEY is the name of the file and the content is all the 4 columns as is. Also the location of these new files should be configurable. Anyone suggest an efficient way to do this? both the "real time" monitoring and file splitting.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried if there is any. And please read the [Stackoverflow help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to write better questions.

Comment: If you don't even know where to start with this problem, then at least show us what research you've done, and point out exactly which concepts or techniques you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [David's generator tricks from python](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/) . A sample program that would achieve your objective would be something like:

```
import time
import csv
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = open("run/foo/access-log","r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    for line in loglines:
        z = line.split(",")  # if it is comma separated, change delimiter if required
        with open("/path/to/csv/"+z[0]+".csv",'wb') as f:
            wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter = ";")
            wr.writerow(z[1:])
```